# How to say "I want to talk to you about many things"

Tags: translation

I'm not sure how to say "I want to talk to you about many things", is 「/Name/に話したいものがたくさんある」okay?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is already good, but you have to use [こと instead of もの](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/generic-nouns/) because a topic of a conversation is not tangible.

> I want to talk to you about many things.
>   あなたに たくさんの **こと**で 話をしたい。
>
> There are many things I want to tell you.
>   あなたに 話したい **こと**が たくさん あります。

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who/relationship but, I would just say something like

> いろいろを話したいな。

or

> いろいろを話し合いたいですね。